# How do I make a generic authentication service?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security

I wrote a chain of **spring applications**, each of which performs some unique functionality. It is a stretch to call this combination of separated services a **microservice architecture**. And now, I would like to **implement spring-security**. However, I think it's silly to implement authorization and authentication functionality for each of the services.

Can you advise **how right it is** to make one more service which would serve as a **common place for authorization and authentication?** And already in each of the already written "microservices" I would check this authorization.

For example, I see the **following path to a "microservice"**. The client makes a **request to the common security service** and gets some kind of **jwt token** there and with this jwt token **goes to any of the services** and gets **authorized** there. In this case, this jwt token determines what rights are granted to this user. I would like to control access to end-points within the applications themselves, and get the jwt token from the outside.

The most important question. **Is it possible** to implement this? If it's possible, **is it the right** way to do it?

I would be immensely grateful for any examples or articles on the subject!

Comment: "*Is it possible to implement this?*" Yes. "*is it the right way to do it?*" No. Don't roll your own auth. Use Okta or MS Entra or something. Spring Security integrates with both.

Comment: As Michael already pointed out, don't implement it yourself. You might want to look for OAuth 2.0 or OpenID Connect (which is based on OAuth) and use any identity and authorization server you want, like Keycloak, WSO2, Okta etc. - or an online service like Auth0 or any provided by the cloud providers. The approach is basically to define and assign roles in that service/server, pass them in a JWT or via some other means, and have your services check for the user having those roles.